# Make SOAP request from WSDL in Spring

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to do some SOAP requests using this wsdl file (from SoapUI examples)

```
<wsdl:definitions name="sample" targetNamespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.soapui.org/sample/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/">
         <xsd:element name="searchResponseContent">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:ItemType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
         <xsd:complexType name="ItemType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
               <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
      <wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="loginResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="sessionid" type="xsd:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="searchRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="sessionid" type="xsd:string"/>
      <wsdl:part name="searchstring" type="xsd:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="searchResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="searchresult" element="tns:searchResponseContent"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="login_faultMsg">
      <wsdl:part name="loginFault" type="xsd:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="search_faultMsg">
      <wsdl:part name="searchFault" type="xsd:string"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="ISampleService">
      <wsdl:operation name="login">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:loginRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:loginResponse"/>
         <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:login_faultMsg"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="search">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:searchRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:searchResponse"/>
         <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:search_faultMsg"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ISampleService">
      <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="login">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.soapui.org/sample/login"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault"/>
         </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="search">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.soapui.org/sample/search"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.soapui.org/sample/"/>
         </wsdl:output>
         <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault"/>
         </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="SampleService">
      <wsdl:port name="SamplePort" binding="tns:ServiceSoapBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://www.soapui.org/sample"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate the complex types defined in the wsdl, but now I don't understand how to make a soap request, for example doing a login or search request.
I think I have to use WebServiceGatewaySupport class to do the request, but I don't understand how to that.
Can you help me, thank you?